# Using Required Field Validator to Disable ListBox

Tags: asp.net, validation, requiredfieldvalidator

Pretty simple question.

I have a few ASP RequiredFieldValdators checking some text boxes.

Out of the box, it checks validation when a button is pressed, basically disabling it unless all fields are met.

I also have a listbox with a bunch of data points, which load new data into the text boxes that are being validated.

I want to make sure the user can't switch data points before all required fields are met.  How can I "disable" the listbox  (via validation) similar to how the buttons are "disabled"

Please feel free to ask for clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just set CauseValidation="true" for the listbox.  This prevented me from changing data points when the current fields were invalid

Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

The asp.net validators do not provide this kind of functionality to conditionally disable the controls. You will need to write your own validator (pretty tough, or see [Peter Blum](http://peterblum.com)). Better handle it in blur event handler for the textbox.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#<%=yourTextbox.ClientID%>").blur(function(){
         $("#<%=yourDropDown.ClientID%>").attr("disabled","disabled");
         ValidateInputs();//You will validate inputs in this function
      });
   });
 </script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
  function ValidateInputs(){
     //.....Validations......
     if(validattions okay){ 
        $("#<%=yourDropDown.ClientID%>").attr("disabled","");
      }
  }
 </script>
```

PS:- I'm supposing you are using jQuery, if not please get some time and visit [jQuery.com](http://jquery.com) and give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Write CauseValidation="false" on the cancel button of apsx page.